# How to dynamically remove a `md-tooltip` with Angular Material?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have a basic `md-button` with a `md-tooltip` inside. Although, I require a way to globally remove all tooltips from my website if the user is on a mobile device.

```
<md-button class="md-primary md-raised">
   Hello
   <md-tooltip>This is a buttons tooltip</md-tooltip>
</md-button>
```

After the template is loaded and directives have run, the above gets converted into the following:

```
<button class="md-primary md-raised md-button md-ink-ripple" type="button" ng-transclude="" aria-label="Hello">
    <span class="ng-scope">
       Hello
    </span>
    <div class="md-ripple-container"></div>
</button>
```

There button element no longer contains the `md-tooltip`, otherwise I'd simply just remove the tooltip element.

The reason for wanting to do this is because on mobile, the `md-tooltip` eats the button click. Therefore having the tooltip displayed on the first click and the buttons click action on the second click. This is definitely not a desirable effect.

How can I remove all tooltips from all elements on my page so that my buttons click action is the first click/tap instead of the second?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so I've successfully implemented my suggestions earlier, here's the [DEMO](http://codepen.io/louiealmeda/pen/ZQdvzY?editors=1010)

I created another version of `md-tooltip` just to override angular material's version of it. Then I created an `angular.decorator` to choose which directive version of `md-tooltip` will angular use.

```
app.directive('mdTooltip', function(){  //create your overriding directive
  return{
    replace: true,
    template: '<span style="display:none"></span>',
    scope: {}, //create an isolated scope
    link: function(scope, element){
       element.remove();
       scope.$destroy();
    }
  };
});

app.decorator('mdTooltipDirective',function($delegate){

  var version = 0;
  var onMobile = false;//do your checking here

  if(onMobile) //here comes the switching 
    version = 1;

  return [$delegate[version]];

});
```

the `Directive` word in `mdTooltipDirective` is important, to say to angular that we want to select it for the Directive not a service.

EDIT: I added a link function and removed the element that is placed by the overriding directive

---

I don't see any mention on their docs on how to do this.

There are two ways that I can think of to work around this.

1. `display: none` all `<md-tooltip>` if your on a mobile device.
2. override the `mdTooltip` directive then conditionally `$compile` the original md-tooltip or a blank one (if you are on a mobile)

Comment: Unfortunately, that first solution will not work. On mobile, the `md-tooltip` is eating the buttons click action. Therefore, a double tap on mobile is required to perform the buttons click action. I believe your section option may be worth a shot. Any chance of an example?

Comment: @Fizzix I edited my question and implemented my suggestion number 2

Comment: Perfectttt. Doesn't take over the mobile click anymore. Works very well, nice work!

Comment: Hahaha! Great! Thanks :)

Comment: If I have an `ng-repeat` and have `md-tooltips` inside of that repeat somewhere, your code seems to do a lot of harm and destroys the data within the `ng-repeat` and leavs blank data displaying as curly braces instead of converting them. This may have something to do with the `scope.$destroy()` I'm guessing?

Comment: The `element.remove()`  and `scope.$destroy()` are optional, though you'll have the unnecessary elements placed on your html. Is it working well if you remove those?

Comment: @Fizzix, I edited my answer, basically, I created an isolated scope so that it will not destroy the scope the directive is in. It's now fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

As per this [**`issue`**](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/4176), the `md-tooltip` is the buggy code.

In that case, I suggest you show the tooltip code based on the condition, i.e. only display the content if you are in a web browser.

For this task, you can use the [**`ng-device-detector`**](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-device-detector) lib:

Comment: But what if I have over 100 `md-tooltips` within my site? I'd have to manually go to each one and add a condition... Would take ages.

Comment: Then you need to put the `md-tooltips' initialization in condition

Answer (score 0):

```
HTML

<md-tooltip md-direction="bottom"  class="tooltip">Tooltip Bottom</md-tooltip>

CSS

@media(max-width:599px) {
md-tooltip.tooltip {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```